# How can I create a patch to insert a menu into an executable file which does not have a menu?

Tags: patching

I need help writing a patch that inserts a menu into an application which does not have one. When I an executable file in a resource editor, I found the menu and I saved the file again and it doesn't show up. I then used OllyDbg to disassemble the executable and wrote the wrong code, saved it. When I clicked the application, it still does not show up. And I do not know how to write a proper patch for this. What else should I do if none of the options work?

I used HxD for hex editing for making the menu appear (I was hoping to see the manu) by adding the commands

CreateMenu
LoadMenu
AppendMenu
InsertMenuItem...

but nothing worked. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think the last time I did this I added/edited the menu resource, however you need to add code to handle the menu selections which may mean jumping to a code cave then jumping back. Enabling menus for crippleware is usually a lot simpler.